# VirtualBox Sharing Folders with Windows 10 Guest and Ubuntu Host

Tags: virtualbox

I am trying to share a folder between a Windows 10 Host and Ubuntu Guest. I have followed all the steps:

Installed guest additions
Settings->Shared Folders-> Added shared folder
Tried to mount the folder using "sudo mount -t vboxsf SharedFolder SharedFolder_Location

Nothing is working. The folder never even shows up in the Ubuntu guest. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here, but I am about to give up on VirtualBox. As a side note, I also can't get the copy and paste feature to work either even after setting it to "Bi-directional"

Comment: It does work. You must install Guest Additions, and read the manual - then it's easy.

Comment: I did install Guest Additions. I've uninstalled and reinstalled the virtual machine as well. Still no luck.

Comment: "Nothing is working." is not very helpful. What is the error message to the mount command?

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of virtual-box (`v5.2 for example`), I complete this task **without command line**:

1. Open the guest system
2. **Settings -> Shared Folders -> Add**, then select the real directory of the folder and name it,  and select auto-mounting and fixed-mounting (I use a version not in English, but I think you can see some options similar)
3. **Restart the guest system**, then you can see the folder by GUI, like My Computer in win10, or in the sidebar of files in ubuntu

By the way, I have installed the **VboxGuestAddtions** and the **Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack**